# printing line number of the source codes Stmt using clang libtooling

Tags: clang, llvm, libtooling

Hello I'm working with clang libtooling. I need to take a .c file and print the names of all functions present and the lines the function declaration is in. In the ASTRecursive class I have function VisitFunctionDecl and have found the functions but am very confused how to find the line number of the Stmts.

Answer (score 1):

Given a `FunctionDecl *f`, `f->getSourceRange()` is its source range (beginning and end). Given a `SourceRange sr`, `sr.getBegin()` gives you a `SourceLocation` which is the beginning of the range.

Look up the documentation / declarations of the classes mentioned for more details.

Comment: I want print these line or show them on the terminal. How can I do that?

Comment: Given a SourceLocation, you can use its `print` or `printToString` methods and pass it a `SourceManager` (possibly from your matched `ASTContext`).